# Android com leitor de código de barras externo

Tags: java, android

Olá, tenho uma tela com campos para digitação e um campo específico onde vou usar o leitor de código de barras externo. O problema é que o scanner desativa o teclado virtual. Alguma idéia de como deixar os dois ativos?

Comment: não dá para você colocar um botão que alterna entre os dois?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode forçar a exibição do `Soft Keyboard` para o campo de digitação do código, independente se o `EditText` possui foco, usando o `InputMethodManager` dessa maneira:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idDoEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                         getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

E para esconder programaticamente:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                         getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Fonte: [Pergunta do SO EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused)

Comment: Quer dizer que o nosso SOPT não é oficial? :)

Comment: Eitcha @Piovezan, é beta :P Vou mudar isso.

Comment: Ahah, chato esse Piovezan. :)